# Create account in Sentry

Tags: logging, sentry

Can I create a new account in Sentry? How?

*It necessary for add user: "You may add a user by their username if they already have an account.".*

TIA.

Comment: Where are you trying to create an account? getsentry.com or your own hosted instance?

Comment: "You may add a user by their username if they already have an account." - wath it's mean? "already have an account" where?

Comment: I add user in 127.0.0.1:9000/admin/ and then add user in Sentry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending a hour or so on this issue I've finally found the answer. Sentry has user management here: `<http://yoursentry.url>/manage/users/`.

Comment: I add user in 127.0.0.1:9000/admin/

Answer (score 6):

I do the following procedure to create another account in a local Sentry:

Suppose Sentry port is `9000`:

1. Log in with the original account
2. Go to this address `http://127.0.0.1:9000/settings/sentry/members/`
3. Invite a user with the email and the role then click on <kbd>Add
   Member</kbd>
4. Click on the new created invitation.
5. Copy the Invite Link to the clipboard.
6. Sign out from the original user.
7. Go to the copied link (i.e.
   `http://127.0.0.1:9000/accept/6/ab1acc5a37cf4e84a1f75a51c7485f06b01dcad2219540d1b4490a1e1dcbd705/`
   )
8. Click on <kbd>Create a new account</kbd>
9. Now, the `Register` tab will appear next to the `Login`.
10. Enter a new email, name, and password in the Register tab then click on <kbd>Register</kbd>
11. Click on <kbd>Join to a Sentry organization</kbd>

---

[**NOTE**]:

- With this address `http://127.0.0.1:9000/admin` and with the original
  user, you can access to Sentry `User` table, and change the account
  Role and Organization or you could create a new user.
- This method has been tested on Sentry 9.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I have the user register in http://SOMEHOST:9000/auth/login/sentry/ then I assign the user to a team. Each project is assigned to a team.

Sentry on-premise version: master HEAD is at 177ed0ef (committed last November 11, 2016)

Answer (score 0):

My user management screen is here.

http://yourSentryURL.com/organizations/sentry/members/